# Bad request response 400 on ajax call spring controller

Tags: http-status-code-404

Here is my ajax request:

```
var segmentName = $('#segmentName').val();
if (segmentName.length == 0) {

    alert('Segment Name Cannot be empty');
    return;
}
var selectedValue = []; 
$('#multiselect_to_1 :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 

    selectedValue = $(selected).text(); 
});
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    url : 'saveSegmentScheme.htm',
    data :JSON.stringify({
        "segmentName" : segmentName,
        "selectedValue": selectedValue
    }),
    success : function(data) {
    //  alert("Data successfully inserted");
        console.log(data);
    },
```

Here is my controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveSegmentScheme.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveSegmentScheme(@ModelAttribute("analyzerBean") AnalyzerBean analyzerBean, BindingResult result,
            @RequestParam("segmentName") String segmentName, @RequestParam("selectedValue") String selectedValue,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        logger.debug("Entered and leaving from saveSegmentScheme()...");
```

Comment: What is your question? SO is not a debugging tool :)

Comment: am getting 404 (Bad request) response every time i request above ajax call.